# Exit command can't exit bash shell after showing a service info?

Tags: bash, exit, systemctl

So simple a bash script which contains only two lines.

```
cat show.sh
systemctl status cron
exit  0
```

Executed it with root in terminal.

```
bash  show.sh
```

All info about cron.service show on terminal.

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-08-10 06:51:18 EDT; 13h ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
```

Why the show.sh is not in exit status,to add a click on `q` will exit show.sh,why `exit 0` not execute?how to trigger it?
My expection:show info about cron.service on terminal and exit show.sh script.
Half done for my show.sh,just show info about cron.service on terminal.
It is meaningful that a long script automate a job ,the above two lines is the last step to show the whole script's status.

Comment: `exit` is not run until `systemctl` finished. If `systemctl status cron` is waiting for you to press `q`, then, well, there's your answer.

Comment: ...if you don't want systemctl to do that, I'd suggest adjusting its settings to no longer launch a pager.

Comment: BTW, I would suggest leaving out the `exit 0` line. If you don't have it, the script exits with the status of the last command it ran (that is, the default behavior is `echo "$?"`), which is useful: It passes through the exit status of `systemctl`, so your script's caller knows that result.

Comment: (err, I meant `exit "$?"`, not `echo "$?"`, of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `--no-pager` to `systemctl`, as follows:

```
systemctl --no-pager status cron
```

Otherwise, systemctl runs `less` (or a program like it), which doesn't exit until `q` is pressed; consequently, control isn't directly handed back to your script.

---

See the related question on our sister site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) at [Can I prevent `service foo status` from paging its output through `less`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343168/can-i-prevent-service-foo-status-from-paging-its-output-through-less)